# Div drop down and up

Tags: jquery, html, dropdownbox

Have the following script to get a div that Drop down when I click on it.
But how can you do so that I it goes up if you click outside the div: a?

[Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/GVYEd/1)

html

```
<div id="favorite_holder">
   <span class="price">click here</span>
</div>
<div id="favorite_container" style="display: none;">
    content here...
</div>
```

css

```
#favorite_holder {
padding:17px 6px 1px 6px;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
background:url(../img/icon_favorite.png) top center no-repeat #fff;
border-right:1px dotted #dddddd;
cursor:pointer;
}
#favorite_container {
position:absolute;
right:0px;
z-index:9;
width:336px;
margin:0px 0px 0px -87px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size:12px;
color:#202020;
background:#fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
}
```

jquery

```
/* menu - favorite */
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#favorite_holder').click(function() {
    $('#favorite_container').slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$('#favorite_holder').click(function(e) {
    $('#favorite_container').slideToggle("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('#favorite_container').slideUp("fast");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GVYEd/3/

for 2 divs: http://jsfiddle.net/GVYEd/6/

Comment: Thanks for that. It works perfectly. You are a angel of mercy!

Comment: Dammit, this is pretty much my exact code that I was just about to post!  Good job at beating me :-)  Btw, my only difference was I used $('html') instead of $(document).  For my own curiosity, is there any reason to use document instead?

Comment: Quick question if you have two div: s, how do you get the enna to go up if you click down the other?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed: document means the whole page.

Comment: Thought I to, see updated link
[Jsfiddle.net] http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/GVYEd/5/

Comment: @LarsH: What do you want? I am unable to understand. :(

Comment: works right div: na drops up when I click no to.

I have a div clicked down and click div two so stanar div one down (this is after all going up down I click on div two)

Comment: Thanks, version number 6, works exactly as I want. Thank you my friends!

Comment: @JitendraPancholi - and 'html' doesn't mean the whole page?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed: I didn't say that. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721035/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-document-and-html

Comment: @JitendraPancholi - I guess there was miscommunication somewhere.  I asked what the difference was between document and 'html', and you said that document means the whole page... which I took as you saying 'html' doesn't mean that.