# jQuery in IE11 - Difference between $(document).width() and $("html").width()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, getboundingclientrect

So I have this in IE11...

**ROUNDED UP (I think...)**

```
console.log($(document).width()); // 808px;
```

**NOT ROUNDED**

```
console.log($("html")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width); // 807.30993px;
```

**ROUNDED DOWN (or to nearest integer)**

```
console.log($("html").width()); //807px;
```

So apparently, either $(document) and $("html") are the same, and jQuery is rounding the html element down instead of up like the browser. Or IE11 gives the $(document) some extra room, boosting the amount of pixels HIGHER than html?

I thought html was supposed to represent the whole document?

**MY QUESTION:**

Should they be the same width? Like in Firefox, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to a similar question:
[In JavaScript,  the document keyword is a handle on the object that contains the HTMLDocument.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4721134/3556874)
So they are not the same, document is an object , which also contains html for the page.

> Now when you get the width from the html and document.

```
console.log($("html").width());
```

gives you the width of the html.

and `console.log($(document).width());`
**gives you the width of visible part of the document**, so apperently width of `<html>` itself, but there is a difference , if you have applied a margin to `html`, then the width of document is a `sum of width of html and the margin applied to it`.

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/bbke9n59/

```
<div style='background:red;height:30px;'></div>

html{
    margin:20px;
}
```

here, in my browser i get,

```
console.log('html='+$("html").width()); // width 630

console.log('document='+$(document).width());// width 670
```

Exactly, 40px difference in the width, thats only the margin applied to the `html`

Now this was all about chrome and firefox,

> About IE

**IE-9**
when I run the same page on IE-9

```
   console.log('html='+$("html").width()); // width 570
    
    console.log('document='+$(document).width());// width 570
```

No difference in width of html and document( there should have been really)

**IE-11**
when I run the same page on IE-11

```
   console.log('html='+$("html").width()); // width 517
    
    console.log('document='+$(document).width());// width 557
```

Exact difference of 40. just as chrome and firefox showed.

So I am no longer able to reproduce the problem of rounding( in any of the browsers), so for me, I guess the problem is not with the rounding up using jquery(***if that was the problem then jquery would have rounded up the width for `document` and `html` both, and still make them same width***)